# Syntax of app.use(express.static('public'))

Tags: function, express, callback

The code `app.use(express.static('public'))` is used in express apps to set a folder for static files access. I don't understand the syntax used in passing `express.static('public')` to `app.use()` function. My understanding is that when passing a function as an argument (callback) to another function, we only pass the function name.  In the code `app.use(express.static('public'))`, the function `express.static()` is being called inside the arguments section of `app.use()` function. I don't understand the syntax used here. Is there some JavaScript syntax I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`express.static('public')` returns a middleware function when you call it.

So, this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

has the same effect as this:

```
const myStaticFn = express.static('public');
app.use(myStaticFn);
```

So, you are passing a function to `app.use()`.  It's just that calling `express.static('public')` creates a custom function that happens to know the directory it should operation on is 'public'.

If you want to see the code for `express.static()`, you can see it [here](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/9b5a12a76f4d70530d2d2a8c7742e9158ed3c0a4/index.js#L38) where you can see in the middle of the function (after some argument checking), it does this:

```
return function serveStatic (req, res, next) { ... }
```

So, that's the function you end up passing to `app.use()` and you can see it has the perfect signature for a middleware function.

.